# Did President Trump ever answer questions on obstruction to Mueller?

Tags: united-states, law, donald-trump, russian-federation, mueller-investigation

The FBI’s Trump-Russia investigation, overseen by Special Counsel Robert Mueller, has just finished.  Now at some point in the course of the investigation, Mueller’s team sent President Trump a series of questions concerning the collusion part of the investigation, and Trump provided written answers to the question.

At the time, Trump’s lawyer Rudy Giuliani said that these wouldn’t necessarily be the last questions asked, because Mueller also wanted to ask Trump about obstruction of justice, either in person or through more written questions and answers.  Now Trump never sat down for an in-person interview with Mueller’s team, but my question is, did Trump at least answer questions in written form concerning obstruction of justice?

Has Giuliani or anyone else on Trump’s legal team commented on this?

Comment: Do tweets count?

Comment: @Time4Tea No, my question is about answers to Mueller, not public statements about obstruction.

Comment: Not a definitive answer to your question: But, I can't find any public reporting of written responses with regard to OoJ.

Comment: If they had, it would have been all over the news when they did. That doesn't mean no, but if it occurred behind the scenes this question probably isn't answerable for another few months or years when the Mueller report is finally made public.

Comment: What if he tagged Mueller on one of his tweets?  :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### No, Trump was not interviewed, but the president submitted written answers

According to the introductory note of appendix C of [the Mueller report](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/04/18/politics/full-mueller-report-pdf/index.html) (page C-1, page 417 in the pdf):

> Beginning in December 2017, this Office sought for more than a year to interview the
> President on topics relevant to both Russian-election interference and obstruction-of-justice. We advised counsel that the President was “subject” of the investigation under the definition of the
> Justice Manual—
> “a person whose conduct is within the scope of the grand jury’s investigation.”
> Justice Manual §9-11.151 (2018). We also advised counsel that “[a]n interview with the President
> is vital to our investigation” and that this Office had “carefully considered the constitutional and
> other arguments raised by . .. counsel, and they d[id] not provide us with reason to forgo seeking
> an interview.
> ”<sub>1</sub> We additionally stated that “it is in the interest of the Presidency and the public
> for an interview to take place” and offered “numerous accommodations to aid the President’s
> preparation and avoid surprise.
> ”<sub>2</sub> After extensive discussions with the Department of Justice about
> the Special Counsel’s objective of securing the President’s testimony, these accommodations
> included the submissions of written questions to the President on certain Russia-related topics.<sub>3</sub>

The three footnotes here refer to letters by the Special counsel to the President's personal counsel.

Note that the questions and the answers submitted by president Trump start on page 427 of the pdf.